# How to do a cast from void* to a c struct

Tags: c, casting, adt, void-pointers

I have this struct

```
typedef struct tournament_t
{
 Map players;
}*Tournament;
```

the Map Adt used in the struct is generic and uses this typedef for `void*`

```
/** Data element data type for map container */
typedef void *MapDataElement;
```

I want a Copy Function for the Tournament struct and it has to be with type `MapDataElement`
so this is the function

```
MapDataElement tournamentCopy(MapDataElement tournament)
{
 //some code
 Tournament ptr = *(Tournament*)tournament;
    copy->players=mapCopy(ptr->players);
//some code
}
```

the problem is that no matter what i do
`ptr->players` is always null
when I tried to change the type that the function gets from `MapDataElement` to `Tournament` everything worked fine , However I am not allowed to change it
so ... any ideas?

Comment: How is the argument `tournament` set? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How are you calling `tournamentCopy`? Also, please don't hide pointers behind typedefs. It makes things very confusing to read. `typedef struct tournament_t {...} Tournament; Tournament *ptr;` instead of `typedef struct tournament_t {...}* Tournament; Tournament ptr;`

Comment: Hiding pointers behind `typedef` is a typical source of a lot of confusion... Too bad that you seems forced to use that.

Comment: Now DON'T hide pointers in typedefs! So `typedef void *MapDataElement;` should be `typedef void MapDataElement;`

Comment: What else did you change when you changed the type of the parameter from `MapDataElement` to `Tournament`? Is the parameter supposed to point to a `struct tournament_t`? If so, change `Tournament ptr = *(Tournament*)tournament;` to `Tournament ptr = (Tournament)tournament;`.

Answer (score 0):

You have pointer confusion. Use:

```
typedef struct tournament_t
{
    Map players;
}Tournament;


typedef struct mapdataelement_t
{
     // definition
} MapDataElement;
```

and now:

```
MapDataElement *tournamentCopy(MapDataElement *tournament)
{
    Tournament *ptr = (Tournament *)tournament;
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of all your problems is trying to hide pointers behind typedefs which makes the code needlessly complex and unreadable - you are only creating a bunch of problems for yourself with this.

Simply do:

```
typedef struct 
{
  Map players;
} tournament_t;
```

> I want a Copy Function for the Tournament struct and it has to be with type MapDataElement

Ok so make `MapDataElement` something that makes sense, `void*` probably does not. If you want it to be some sort of generic item container then typedef it as such:

```
typedef struct
{
  void* data;
  size_t size;
  // whatever makes sense to include here, an enum to list types perhaps?
} MapDataElement;
```

---

And finally, modern C allows you to do type safe, type-generic programming without dangerous void pointers:

```
#define something_copy(x) _Generic((x), \
  tournament_t: tournament_copy,        \
  thingie_t:    thingie_copy) (x)
```

This means that the function-like macro "something_copy" will call the relevant specific function based on the type passed. Or if you pass a wrong type not supported - a compiler error.

Comment: Could you show how the macro can call two different functions based on two different types?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Sure I guess. Added a line to the example code.